# What is cat for and what is it doing here?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this script I'm studying and I would like to know what is `cat` doing in this section.

```
if cat downloaded.txt | grep "$count" >/dev/null
    then
        echo "File already downloaded!"
    else
        echo $count >> downloaded.txt
        cat $count | egrep -o "http://server.*(png|jpg|gif)" | nice -n -20 wget --no-dns-cache -4 --tries=2 --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=cookies.txt --referer=http://server.com/wallpaper/$number -i -
        rm $count   
fi
```

Comment: It keeps the mice down.

Comment: Smells like someone missed `-m` in the wget documentation...

Comment: (`cat`, of course, spits out the file into the pipe.  Then `grep` or `egrep` swallows the pipe input and does it's thing.)

Comment: Here it's a "Useless Use of Cat" (http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) - grep accepts file arguments, so the first line could instead be `if grep "$count" downloaded.txt >/dev/null`.

Comment: See also [Useless Use of Cat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams and `-q` in the `grep` documentation, and how quotes work, and how to use standard error, and … #sigh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like most cats, this is a [useless cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Instead of:

```
if cat downloaded.txt | grep "$count" >/dev/null
```

It could have been written:

```
if grep "$count" download.txt > /dev/null
```

In fact, because you've eliminated the pipe, you've eliminated issues with which exit value the `if` statement is dealing with.

Most Unix cats you'll see are of the *useless* variety. However, people like cats almost as much as they like using a `grep`/`awk` pipe, or using multiple `grep` or `sed` commands instead of combining everything into a single command.

The `cat` command stands for `concatenate` which is to allow you to *concatenate* files. It was created to be used with the `split` command which splits a file into multiple parts. This was useful if you had a really big file, but had to put it on floppy drives that couldn't hold the entire file:

```
split -b140K -a4 my_really_big_file.txt my_smaller_files.txt.
```

Now, I'll have `my_smaller_files.txt.aaaa` and `my_smaller_files.txt.aaab` and so forth. I can put them on the floppies, and then on the other computer. (Heck, I might go all high tech and use [UUCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP) on you!).

Once I get my files on the other computer, I can do this:

```
cat my_smaller_files.txt.* > my_really_big_file.txt
```

And, that's one cat that isn't useless.

Answer (score 0):

`cat` prints out the contents of the file with the given name (to the standard output or to wherever it's redirected). The result can be piped to some other command (in this case, `(e)grep` to find something in the file contents). Concretely, here it tries to download the images referenced in that file, then adds the name of the file to `downloaded.txt` in order to not process it again (this is what the check in `if` was about).

http://www.linfo.org/cat.html

Answer (score 0):

"cat" is a unix command that reads the contents of one or more files sequentially and by default prints out the information the user console ("stdout" or standard output).

In this case cat is being used to read the contents of the file "downloaded.txt", the pipe "|" is redirecting/feeding its output to the grep program, which is searching for whatever is in the variable "$count" to be matched with.